# What do I need to do to have my SettingDefinitionProvider picked up by the Abp framework?

Tags: abp

I am using the ABP framework and am trying to use a custom setting definition provider as shown below

```
using Volo.Abp.Settings;

namespace MyConsoleDemo;

public class MySettingProvider : SettingDefinitionProvider
{
    public override void Define(ISettingDefinitionContext context)
    {
        context.Add(
            new SettingDefinition("MySetting", "MyValue"));
    }
}
```

using this module

```
using Volo.Abp.Modularity;
using Volo.Abp.SettingManagement;

namespace MyConsoleDemo;

[DependsOn(typeof(AbpSettingManagementDomainModule))]
public class MyConsoleDemoModule : AbpModule
{
}
```

and this Program.cs class

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MyConsoleDemo;
using Volo.Abp;
using Volo.Abp.Settings;

// Create the ABP application container
using var application = await AbpApplicationFactory.CreateAsync<MyConsoleDemoModule>();

// Initialize/start the ABP Framework (and all the modules)
await application.InitializeAsync();

var settingProvider = application.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ISettingProvider>();

var myValue = await settingProvider.GetOrNullAsync("MySetting");

await application.ShutdownAsync();
```

Yet when I run the console app I get the following error:

**Volo.Abp.AbpException: Undefined setting: MySetting**

According to [the documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Settings) ABP automatically discovers this class and registers the setting definitions.

Where am I going wrong? If I put a breakpoint in my setting provider class it never gets hit either.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the problem was my DependsOn on my module, it should have been AbpSettingsModule

```
[DependsOn(typeof(AbpSettingsModule))]
public class MyConsoleDemoModule : AbpModule
{
}
```

and I should have configured Autofac when creating the factory

```
 using var application = await AbpApplicationFactory.CreateAsync<MyConsoleDemoModule>(options =>
 {
     options.UseAutofac();
 });
```